# Delete one duplicate cell out of table range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete duplicate cells out of a specific table range, but one duplicate (the first from the top) should not be deleted. Column A of the table should not be searched for duplicates. It is also possible that there is no content in the table starting from column B.

This is how it looks (sorry for the numbering, wasn't sure how to format it otherwise):

1. ABCDE
2. a
3. bbcde
4. cbcef
5. ddefgh

This is what i want:

1. ABCDE
2. a
3. bbcde
4. cf
5. dgh

I tried to do this with two for loops. The first one loops through each row and the second one through each column. If it finds a duplicate, it should delete it.

But I guess I have messed something up with the for loops there, because sometimes it deletes some weird stuff and not the duplicates..

```
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
Dim C1row As Long
Dim C2row As Long
Dim C2column As Long
Dim C2TotalRows As Long
Dim CustID As String
Dim NoDups As Long

Set reportsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle44")
reportsheet.Activate
Sucher_rowTotalRows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) ' switchen durch Reihen
Duplikat_row = 1 'für aeuseres For zum durchswitschen zwischen den Ist
Sucher_row = 1
Duplikat_column = 2
Sucher_column = 2

testwert = Cells(Duplikat_row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Do While Duplikat_row <= Sucher_rowTotalRows

    If Cells(Duplikat_row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column = 1 Then
    Duplikat_row = Duplikat_row + 1
    Sucher_row = Sucher_row + 1
    End If

    duplikat = reportsheet.Cells(Duplikat_row, Duplikat_column).Value

     For Sucher_row = 1 To Sucher_rowTotalRows
        For Sucher_column = 2 To (Cells(Sucher_row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) '' Breite der Spalte
            If duplikat = Cells(Sucher_row, Sucher_column).Value Then '' Falls gesuchtes und gesuchert uebereinstimmt

                Cells(Sucher_row, Sucher_column).Delete xlShiftToLeft '' löschen und nach links verschieben
                Sucher_column = Sucher_column - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Sucher_column = Sucher_column + 1 '' Suchspalte eins weiter
    Next
    Duplikat_row = Duplikat_row + 1 ''suchreihe eins weiter
Loop
```

Any idea what is going wrong there? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
duplikat = reportsheet.Cells(Duplikat_row, Duplikat_column).Value

For Sucher_row = 1 To Sucher_rowTotalRows
    For Sucher_column = 2 To (Cells(Sucher_row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) '' Breite der Spalte
        Do While duplikat = Cells(Sucher_row, Sucher_column).Value  '' Falls gesuchtes und gesuchert uebereinstimmt
            If Sucher_row = Duplikat_row And Sucher_column = Duplikat_column Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                Cells(Sucher_row, Sucher_column).Delete xlShiftToLeft '' löschen und nach links verschieben
            End If
        Loop
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works for the first duplicate, but it lacks switching to the next duplicate it should look for. Given the above mentioned example, your code deletes all the "b" but it lacks to delete "c", "e", "f"... Hope you get what i meant...

Comment: Also, excel crashes when i try to run your code. I just saw the error message once, and i think it was "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)".. But when i go through with F8 it works for the first duplicate.